# Always position "GOT IT" button of MaterialShowcaseView on the bottom left corner of the screen

Tags: android

I'm using the following library: https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView
I've been trying to find a way (for 2 days straight!) to always position the "GOT IT" button on the bottom left corner of the screen. How do I achieve that simply and effectively?

I will immediately accept the working answer. As you can see, I have a history of always accepting answers.

[image]

With Osama's answer, I get error:

```
com.example.me.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.me.myapplication, PID: 4445
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot start this animator on a detached view!
        at android.view.RenderNode.addAnimator(RenderNode.java:812)
        at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:300)
        at android.view.RenderNodeAnimator.setTarget(RenderNodeAnimator.java:282)
        at android.animation.RevealAnimator.<init>(RevealAnimator.java:37)
        at android.view.ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(ViewAnimationUtils.java:55)
        at uk.co.deanwild.materialshowcaseview.CircularRevealAnimationFactory.animateInView(CircularRevealAnimationFactory.java:29)
        at uk.co.deanwild.materialshowcaseview.MaterialShowcaseView.animateIn(MaterialShowcaseView.java:825)
        at uk.co.deanwild.materialshowcaseview.MaterialShowcaseView$1.run(MaterialShowcaseView.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.me.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import uk.co.deanwild.materialshowcaseview.MaterialShowcaseView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // single example
        new MaterialShowcaseView.Builder(this)
                .setTarget(findViewById(R.id.hi))
                .setDismissText("GOT IT")
                .setContentText("This is some amazing feature you should know about! Indeed, this is just an example of a bug that can be easily fixed!")
                .show();

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.me.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.419" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lib is based on [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView), take a look at it.

You can also go to the `showcase_content.xml` at the library module and put the `tv_dismiss` that is the "GOT IT" `TextView` into a `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_dismiss"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Go to `MaterialShowcaseView.java` and empty the `applyLayoutParams()` method and update the `setDelay` to 1000 
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how can I edit `showcase_content.xml` ? I have this in my build.grade: `compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0'`

Comment: download the simple from github, go to file > import module >select the library from the downloaded files, go to your gradle file add add this `compile project(':library')` to your dependencies

Comment: There's no such thing as  file > import module  in android studio

Comment: file > new > import module sorry

Comment: let me try it and I will let you know in a few minutes

Comment: Excellent support with a working answer! Great work, answer accepted. If I have more issues, I'll tell you.

Comment: Also, what's the reason behind updating the setDelay to 1000?

Comment: the animation get started before the view in initialized as i think

Comment: But, the problem now is that the ContentText does not get automatically positioned like before... Can we fix this please? I only want "GOT IT" to be in a fixed place.

Comment: Yes, but then the app crashes

Answer (score 0):

Within the builder, add the following code.

```
mDismissButton.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Comment: Within the builder.

Comment: Can you give an example please?